# How to add files to an bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to add files that match *.tar.gz to an array

I've tried

```
shopt -s *.gz
shopt -s nullglob
array=(*)
```

Comment: `array=(*.tar.gz)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any glob to populate an array, so `tarballs=(*.tar.gz)` would work.

PS: `shopt -s *.gz` is not going to set any valid options.

Answer (score -1):

I used    `array=($(ls *.tar.gz))` and it worked probably the same as your solution.

Comment: You didn't try that in a directory in which a tar.gz file has whitespace in its name.